# Wrap type parameters?

Tags: c#, types, type-parameter

If I have a C# class:

```
public class MyFactory<TWidget, TGadget, TGizmo, TThing> 
    where TWidget: IWidget
    where TGadget: IGadget
    where TGizmo: IGizmo
    where TThing: IThing, new()
    {
      public TThing CreateThing(ThingModel model) {
        // create Thing here
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to package up those types into something shorter?  In other words, something like this:

```
ThingModel model = this.ThingModel;
TTypeList typeList = this.TypeList; // the list wraps TNativeWidget, TNativeGadget, TNativeGizmo, and TNativeThing
MyFactory<TTypeList> factory = new Factory(typeList);
TNativeThing thing = factory.CreateThing(model);
```

Comment: My first question is why does your factory require such constraints? Just have your factory methods return interfaces .. and move on.

Comment: I had shortened the question for purposes of simplicity.  But in reality, there are more constraints running around.  For example, IGadget might actually be IGadget<TWidget>, and the gadget has to be able to call foo(someWidget).  But it won't be able to accept an arbitrary widget, just an object of TNativeWidget.  It's not impossible that I'm mistaken, but I think that requires the type parameters to go into the factory.

Comment: Side note: Have you looked at any DI framework - it may be easier to use existing solution than inventing your own. I.e. [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)